# VB script: if file exists then run if not then end

Tags: file, vbscript, operating-system

I'm looking to use a script to go about disabling a file (REAgentc.exe) on Windows 7 machines and if it does not exist (i.e. on XP machines) then end. Below is what I've got so far but can anyone assist me in implementing the rest of what I'm after? My knowledge on VB script is admittedly not great but any help that can be offered forward would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
'Declare Variables
Dim strApp 
Dim arrPath
Dim strPath
Dim strAppPath

' main if statement to run the script and call functions and sub's
If (CheckRegistryForValue)= True Then
   'msgbox( strPath & " I am here")
   WScript.Quit (0)
Else 
   RunCommand
   WriteRegkey
   WScript.Quit (0)
End If 

'Sub to run the REAgent disable command
Sub RunCommand
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   strApp = "C:\Windows\System32\REAgentc.exe /disable"
   arrPath = Split(strApp, "\")

   For i = 0 To Ubound(arrPath) - 1
     strAppPath = strAppPath & arrPath(i) & "\"
   Next 

   objShell.CurrentDirectory = strAppPath
   objShell.Run(strApp)
End Sub

'Function to check registry for value, Return check registry for value
Function CheckRegistryForValue
   Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   On Error Resume Next
   dong = wshShell.RegRead ("HKLM\SOFTWARE\REAgent\")
   If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
      CheckRegistryForValue = False
   Else 
      CheckRegistryForValue = True
   End If
End Function

' sub to write registery key to flag computers that the script has run On
Sub WriteRegkey
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
   strComputer = "."

   Set ObjRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel = impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

   strPath = "SOFTWARE\REAgent\Script Complete"
   Return = objRegistry.CreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strPath)
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats wrong with it/fails/does it not do?

Comment: Hi there, the above excerpt actually works fine. I'm just unsure about how to implement a function to find whether the file exists/whether a machine is 7 or XP

Comment: This script already does what you are trying to do.  I don't understand what more you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `RunCommand` to detect & run;

```
dim FSO, objShell, strApp
set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

'//get system path
strApp = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(1) & "\REAgentc.exe"
if FSO.FileExists(strApp) then
    '//no need to change directory as you have the full path
    objShell.Run(strApp & " /disable")
else
    '//does not exist
end if
```

Comment: Ok thanks, how does one go about doing that? A colleague actually constructed the script initially, I've only just tweaked it slightly with what knowledge I have. Thanks again.